# How to set variable from callback function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have function below.

```
function sh(cmd) {
    exec(cmd, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        std_value.flush();
        std_value.set("error");
      } else {
        console.log({stdout, stderr});
        std_value.flush();
        std_value.set(stdout);
        console.log('std_value in ' + std_value.result);
      }
    });
    console.log('std_value out ' + std_value.result);
    return std_value.result;
}
```

I want to `sh(cmd)` return output of `cmd`. So i am using the following(it is little bit shitty). But `exec` is async function, so outer `std_value.result` will be the value from last call. Is it normal way to create `sh(cmd)`, which wiil return stdout or I should use promises?

Comment: Duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of promise here since you can not return value from the callback/async function.

```
function sh(cmd) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    exec(cmd, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        std_value.flush();
        std_value.set("error");
        reject(err);
      } else {
        console.log({stdout, stderr});
        std_value.flush();
        std_value.set(stdout);
        console.log('std_value in ' + std_value.result);

        resolve(std_value.result);
      }
    });
  })
}

sh().then(val => {
  console.log(val); //this should console the value of std_value.result
})
```

Note: I don't know where did you get `std_value`.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function sh(cmd, callback) {
    exec(cmd, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        std_value.flush();
        std_value.set("error");
        if(!!callback) {
          callback(err);
        }
      } else {
        console.log({stdout, stderr});
        std_value.flush();
        std_value.set(stdout);        
        console.log('std_value in ' + std_value.result);
        if(!!callback) {
          callback(std_value.result);
        }
      }
    });
}

sh("run", function(result) {
  console.log(result);
});
```

You can implement the same with callback like this.